# Access dispatch function as a prop in the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

```
import React from "react";

import "./cart-dropdown.style.scss";
import { CustomButton } from "../cutom-button/custom-button.component";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { StoreState } from "../../redux/root-reducer";
import { ItemModel } from "../../models/ShopPage";
import { CartItem } from "../cart-item/cart-item.component";
import { selectCartItems } from "../../redux/cart/cart.selector";
import { createStructuredSelector } from "reselect";
import { withRouter, RouteComponentProps } from "react-router-dom";

interface CartDropdownStoreProps {
  cartItems: ItemModel[];
}

interface CartDropdownProps extends CartDropdownStoreProps {}

const _CartDropdown: React.FC<CartDropdownProps & RouteComponentProps<{}>> = (
  props: CartDropdownProps & RouteComponentProps<{}>
) => {
  const { cartItems, history } = props;

  return (
    <div className="cart-dropdown">
      <div className="cart-items">
        {cartItems.length ? (
          cartItems.map(cartItem => (
            <CartItem key={cartItem.id} item={cartItem} />
          ))
        ) : (
          <span className="empty-message">Your cart is empty</span>
        )}
      </div>
      <CustomButton onClick={() => history.push("./checkout")}>
        GO TO CHECKOUT
      </CustomButton>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector<StoreState, CartDropdownProps>(
  {
    cartItems: selectCartItems
  }
);

export const CartDropdown = withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(_CartDropdown));
```

When we are not passing the 2nd argument to the connect function we can access dispatch function as a prop inside the component right?
Already did with javascript and no complaints but when I'm trying this with typescript dispatch function is not existing in the props.

I console log all the props which this component get and dispatch *f* exists there.

I don't know why I can't access that!
Can someone help me with this..?

Answer (score 1):

You've provided type of props for `_CartDropdown` as `CartDropdownProps & RouteComponentProps<{}>`. This type does not contain `dispatch`. So from TS point of view `dispatch` is not present.

`console.log` logs object as it represented by JS and sees `dispatch`.

To solve, add type of `dispatch` to props type like below

```
import { Dispatch } from 'redux'

const _CartDropdown: React.FC<CartDropdownProps & RouteComponentProps<{}> & {dispatch: Dispatch}> = /* ... */
```